# rails3: how to change the <body> color for the views of only one controller?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, stylesheet, asset-pipeline

In rails3, I want to have all the views in a specific controller(groups_controller) to have a different body background color. I have a stylesheet groups.css with this rule:

```css
body { 
  background-color: #333
}
```

and I'm including this file in application.css. but the problem is now every controller gets the styles I defined in groups.css. Is there another way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) of the Rails asset pipeline guide for one way to achieve this.

You'll want to move that style rule to the stylesheet for that controller (`groups.css.scss`), and then make sure that each page loads the stylesheet associated with its controller. You can do that by adding the following line to your view template (probably `application.html.erb`):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

You'll probably also need to then make sure that your css manifest doesn't include `groups.css.scss` -- if the rest of your style rules are in `application.css`, you can just remove the `*= require_tree .` directive.

There are other ways you could do the same thing, so if you're not happy with that approach you should be able to find some other alternatives.